# Dynamic panel data

Tags: references, panel-data, dynamic-regression

Can anyone please recommend a good source (academic and basic) for understanding the concepts of dynamic panel data estimation methods and why its preferred over static data analysis?

Comment: you can read B H Baltagi's book "Panel Data Econometrics_ Theoretical Contributions and Empirical Applications"

Answer (score 1):

An approachable introduction is:

Nathaniel Beck and Jonathan N. Katz. 2011. "Modeling Dynamics in Time-Series–Cross-Section Political Economy Data." *Annual Review of Political Science* doi:10.1146/annurev-polisci-071510-103222